# Why should be written page address directly in jquery .load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why should be written page address directly in jquery .load()?

when i write page address directly in jQuery .load() everyting is ok. ex:

```
 function markup(e) {
      $(function () {
            $("#LoadPages").empty();

         $("#LoadPages")
                    .delay(1000)
                    .queue(function(nxt) {
                        $("#LoadPages").load('MyPageAddress');
                        nxt();
                    });

         return false;
});
}
```

but,The same address pass to .load() as parameter .ex:

```
 function markup(e) {
      $(function () {
            $("#LoadPages").empty();

         $("#LoadPages")
                    .delay(1000)
                    .queue(function(nxt) {
                        $("#LoadPages").load(e);
                        nxt();
                    });

         return false;
});
}
```

and call markup function ex:

```
  "<a id='hrefShow' href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='markup(\"/Detail/job/" + item.JobId + " \");'> see more </a>"
```

As you can see in the above code,i pass same address through parameter `e`.
in this case everyting is ok BUT `$("#LoadPages")` div left empty (in the other words get response ,get page content , everyting is work like when i write direct address but LoadPage div is emptym , div doesn't fill with response content)
why ? What is the reason?

Comment: *"As you can see in the above code,i pass same address through parameter e."* – no, actually we *can't* see that because you haven't shown how you call that function. Have you done any debugging (`console.log(e)`)? Have you looked at the browser's network tab to see if the Ajax request is triggered and using the correct address?

Comment: yes address is correct.

Comment: Can you show how you call `makrup` method

Comment: yes of course ,`"<a id='hrefShow' href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='markup(\"/Detail/job/" + item.JobId + " \");'> see more </a>"` . its return `http://localhost:2138/Detail/job/2` and `LoadPage` is empty but when write directly `'/Detail/job/2'` LoadPage fill with response content

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: This is a typical debugging issue. Place some breakpoints in the markup and it will be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i find solution :

```
 onClick='markup(\"/Detail/job/"+item.JobId.toString()+"\");
```